# Optimization Problem Maximize $z= 60x_1+20x_2$

Tags: optimization, operations-research

Restate the absolute value constraint as a combination of two linear constraints: I know how to find the optimal solution (std form, canonical form, simplex algorithm ...etc)
I don't know how to put the absolute value constraint as a combo of 2 linear constraints. What are the procedures?

Example maximize $z=60x_1+20x_2$ such that (constraints): $x_1+x_2 <= 5$ and $|x_1-x_2| <= 2$
where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both $\ge 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!
See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Answer (score 0):

$|x_{1} - x_{2}| \leqslant 2$ holds if $ x_{1} - x_{2} \leqslant 2$ and $x_{1} - x_{2} \geqslant -2$.

Comment: okay thanks so why wouldn't it be x1-x2<= 2 and -x1+x2 <= 2 ? When I put it into standard form will I get the same answer?

Comment: Those are in fact equivalent.